# Change item name color without affecting locale

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to change an item's name color without affecting its actual name over different locales.

To be specific, the two languages used on my server are Czech and English (and maybe Slovak), and I want to have a diamond sword that is still called "Diamond sword" (with the appropriate name over all languages), but with a magenta name (so I only want to change the color of the name, and nothing else).

Is there a tag that can achieve this? I use command blocks, but I can install some Spigot NBT plugins if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `translate` JSON tag to automatically use the translated text of the identifier you choose, then modify that however you like:

```
/give @s diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"translate\":\"item.minecraft.diamond_sword\",\"color\":\"red\"}"}}
```

[image]
[image]

It even changes its description dynamically when switching languages, so it doesn't just resolve once and then stay like that.

You can find all identifiers (like `item.minecraft.diamond_sword`) in the .jar file of the version you play, under `assets/minecraft/lang/en_us.json`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any tips on websites where I could find such information? I looked around everywhere, but all websites about NBT tags in Minecraft just list a few basic ones with each attribute.

Comment: Always the Minecraft wiki, it's the one place for almost everything related to Minecraft: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Raw_JSON_text